# Interactive Brokers API - Javascript Option Price

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, interactive-brokers

Can anyone help me out with a simple Java script to call the last price of an option given the underlying stock symbol, expiration, strike price and exchange? I'm looking to ultimately create a custom Google Sheets function to do this if possible.

Comment: there is no official IB javascript api but someone has made a node impl.  https://github.com/pilwon/node-ib  but your use case is not really what IB has intended for it's api.  Maybe yahoo would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Brian